# What squares are the most active for bishops?

Tags: tactics, positional-play, knights, bishops

For a beginner:

- Where are bishops mostly exchanged or placed?
- Where are knights mostly exchanged or placed?

Comment: Is your question - What are ideal squares where bishops/knights be exchanged?

Answer (score 1):

The f3/f6/c3/c6 tend to be where most knights are exchanged. That is because in beginner play, if the opponent tries to push the pin with h3/h6/a3/a6, the person who has pinned the knight with the bishop typically exchanges, and this tends to be a beginner fault..

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this answer? It matches my intuition, but I'm not aware of any actual data on the subject.

Comment: This is mainly because there aren't many begginer games in databases. A good way is to see that begginers in chess.com usually play the exchange Ruy Lopez, if the play the Ruy Lopez.